# MailChimp API call with OAuth 2 token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am unable to call Mailchimps API 3.0 endpoints such as `/lists` using OAuth 2 tokens.

I already have the token and have the endpoint from the `/metadata` call however, when I attempt to access `/lists` using the below

```
//Get lists
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $datacenter]);
$headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'OAuth ' . $token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Host' => $client_endpoint,
        'User-Agent' => 'oauth2-draft-v10'
    ];
$response = $client->request('GET', 'lists', [
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
$lists = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

Surely there is a simple solution, I am new to OAuth 2 and MailChimp, and struggling to find any information about MailChimp calls using OAuth2 tokens.

I have also tried the below...

```
//Get list data
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $client_endpoint]);
$headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'OAuth ' . $token
    ];

$response = $client->request('GET', 'lists',[
        'user' => 'anystring:' . $token,
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
Log::debug($response);
```

Any help from here would be extremely useful

Comment: i forgot to add that i get error 400 bad request for the first attempt, and error 404 not found for the second

Comment: Could you please provide the response body and headers from the first call? `$response->getBody()->getContents();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that providing the token in the headers in the format `Authorization: OAuth [token]` doesn't work as expected.

I completed the following request using PostMan, code provided for ease of use:

```
// GET https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists
// authorization:"Bearer 0319[redacted]f966" 

$response = $client->get( $datacenter.'/3.0/lists', [
    'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]
]);
$lists = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

*Note: the code is untested, the request is tested*